# C++ member function invocation

Tags: c++, class, methods, member

Ok so often times I have seen the following type of event handling used:

`Connect(objectToUse, MyClass::MyMemberFunction);`

for some sort of event handling where objectToUse is of the type MyClass. My question is how exactly this works. How would you convert this to something that would do `objectToUse->MyMemberFunction()`

Does the `MyClass::MyMemberFunction` give an offset from the beginning of the class that can then be used as a function pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Mats' answer, I'll give you a short example of how you can use a non-static member function in this type of thing. If you're not familiar with pointers to member functions, you may want to check out the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html) first.

Then, consider this (rather simplistic) example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int Mult(int x)
    {
        return (x * x);
    }

    int Add(int x)
    {
        return (x + x);
    }
};

int Invoke(MyClass *obj, int (MyClass::*f)(int), int x)
{ // invokes a member function of MyClass that accepts an int and returns an int
  // on the object 'obj' and returns.
    return obj->*f(x);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    MyClass x; 

    int nine = Invoke(&x, MyClass::Mult, 3);
    int six = Invoke(&x, MyClass::Add, 3);

    std::cout << "nine = " << nine << std::endl;
    std::cout << "six = " << six << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So is `->*` actually the operators -> and * as I assume they are or is this a separate special operator?

Comment: No `->*` is a *distinct* operator from either `->` and `*`. Check out the FAQ - it's at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html for more. It explains pointers to members fairly well.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this uses a `static` member function (that takes a pointer as an argument), in which case the the `objectToUse` is passed in as a parameter, and the `MyMemberFunction` would use `objectToUse` to set up a pointer to a `MyClass` object and use that to refer to member variables and member functions.

In this case `Connect` will contain something like this:

```
void Connect(void *objectToUse, void (*f)(void *obj))
{
     ...
     f(objectToUse);  
     ...
}
```

[It is also quite possible that `f` and `objectToUse` are saved away somewhere to be used later, rather than actually inside Connnect, but the call would look the same in that case too - just from some other function called as a consequence of the event that this function is supposed to be called for].

It's also POSSIBLE to use a pointer to member function, but it's quite complex, and not at all easy to "get right" - both when it comes to syntax and "when and how you can use it correctly". See more [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html).

In this case, `Connect` would look somewhat like this:

```
void Connect(MyClass *objectToUse, void (Myclass::*f)())
{
     ...
     objectToUse->*f();
     ...
}
```

It is highly likely that templates are used, as if the "MyClass" is known in the Connect class, it would be pretty pointless to have a function pointer. A virtual function would be a much better choice.

Given the right circumstances, you can also use virtual functions as member function pointers, but it requires the compiler/environment to "play along". Here's some more details on that subject [which I've got no personal experience at all of: Pointers to virtual member functions. How does it work?

Vlad also points out Functors, which is an object wrapping a function, allowing for an object with a specific behaviour to be passed in as a "function object". Typically this involves a predefined member function or an `operatorXX` which is called as part of the processing in the function that needs to call back into the code.

C++11 allows for "Lambda functions", which is functions declared on the fly in the code, that doesn't have a name. This is something I haven't used at all, so I can't really comment further on this - I've read about it, but not had a need to use it in my (hobby) programming - most of my working life is with C, rather than C++ although I have worked for 5 years with C++ too.

Comment: In particular see [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macro-for-ptr-to-memfn.html).

Comment: It is used as a pointer to a member function __more often__ than a static method.

Comment: What environment are you talking about, Vlad? Many event-driven systems are based on C, and don't cope at all with C++ style member functions, which necessitates use of static functions. In environments that are more C++ oriented, I would have thought that an interface class would be more of a suitable solution, where "MyMemberFunction" is one of the interfaces, and gets called directly in the "Connect" function [or later on as a result of the interface being passed to the Connect function].

Comment: I think that without more context it's impossible for us to *know* whether `Connect` takes a `static` member function or not. Both idioms work in C++ and it depends on what one is trying to do and how.

Comment: Yes, which is why I mentioned both. In my experience [and I think somewhere SO says "we should speak from personal experience", it is more often static than not - but I'm sure that experience depends on exactly which environment you are working on/in]

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The question is tagged C++, not C. There are tons of C++ frameworks based around functors. Some of the most famous — Qt, Boost.Bind, Boost.Signal, Boost.ASIO. Not to mention C++11 lambdas. This answer doesn't touch on any of those, neither it explains how it "works" (or implemented for that matter). It doesn't touch on simple virtual methods, doesn't touch on what happens with multiple inheritance and, I am afraid to mention, on multiple __virtual__ inheritance. What does it answer that OP doesn't know about?

Comment: I have expanded to cover most of the points you pointed out. But I don't know every answer to everything you have described, and I'm not at all sure that the original question REQUIRES those answers.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong here, but as far as I understand,

In C++, functions with the same signature are equal.

C++ member functions with n parameters are actually normal functions with n+1 parameters. In other words, `void MyClass::Method( int i )` is in effect `void (some type)function( MyClass *ptr, int i)`.

So therefore, I think the way Connect would work behind the scenes is to cast the member method signature to a normal function signature. It would also need a pointer to the instance to actually make the connection work, which is why it would need `objectToUse`

In other words, it would essentially be using pointers to functions and casting them to a more generic type until it can be called with the parameters supplied and the additional parameter, which is the pointer to the instance of the object

If the method is static, then a pointer to an instance doesn't make sense and its a straight type conversion. I have not figured out the intricacies involved with non-static methods yet - a look at the internals of [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers) is probably what you want to do to understand that :) Here is how it would work for a static function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void sayhi( std::string const& str )
{
    std::cout<<"function says hi "<<str<<"\n";
}

struct A
{
    static void sayhi( std::string const& str )
    {
        std::cout<<"A says hi "<<str<<"\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (*funptr)(std::string const&);
    funptr hello = sayhi;
    hello("you"); //function says...
    hello = (&A::sayhi); //This is how Connect would work with a static method
    hello("you"); //A says...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right up to the point when virtual functions, multiple inheritance and/or virtual inheritance come into the picture (that's why pointer to function is usually just `sizeof(void*)` bytes and pointer to member is usually twice as large. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

For event handling or callbacks, they usually take two parameters - a callback function and a userdata argument. The callback function's signature would have userdata as one of the parameters.

The code which invokes the event or callback would invoke the function directly with the userdata argument. Something like this for example:

```
eventCallbackFunction(userData);
```

In your event handling or callback function, you can choose to use the userdata to do anything you would like.

Since the function needs to be callable directly without an object, it can either be a global function or a static method of a class (which does not need an object pointer).

A static method has limitations that it can only access static member variables and call other static methods (since it does not have the **this** pointer). That is where userData can be used to get the object pointer.

With all this mind, take a look at the following example code snippet:

```
class MyClass
{
...
public:
    static MyStaticMethod(void* userData)
    {
        // You can access only static members here
        MyClass* myObj = (MyClass*)userdata;
        myObj->MyMemberMethod();
    }

    void MyMemberMethod()
    {
        // Access any non-static members here as well
        ...
    }

...
...
};

MyClass myObject;
Connect(myObject, MyClass::MyStaticMethod);
```

As you can see you can access even member variables and methods as part of the event handling if you could make a static method which would be invoked first which would chain the call to a member method using the object pointer (retrieved from userData).